# Python Group By and Case When Equivalent Relative to R

Tags: python, r, if-statement, pandas-groupby

I am trying to do a case when/if-else statement in Python on a grouped dataframe to create a new variable. I would want to do the following if I was coding in R and I am trying find an operation in Python that's similar and also vectorized.
R code:

```
dt %>% group_by(user,merchant,date) %>%
mutate(
new_variable = case_when(-amount == lag(amount) ~ 2,
                         True ~ 1)
) %>% ungroup()
```

In Python I have tried using np.select:

```
    conditions = [
    (-us_trans['real_amount'] == us_trans['real_amount'].shift(-1)),
    (-us_trans['real_amount'] != us_trans['real_amount'].shift(-1))

]

    values = [
        2, 
        1
        
    ]
```

But I don't know how to use np.select on a grouped dataframe to create a new variable.

I know that I can use `groupby(['user','merchant','date'].apply` and pass an if-else statement but I believe this would be done in a loop and I am trying to do it in a vectorized manner to optimize my code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the slow pandas option:

```
df["new_variable"] = np.where(df.groupby(['user', 'merchant','date'])['amount'].apply(lambda g: g.shift(-1)==-g),2,1)
```

However, using `datatable`, along with `shift()`, `ifelse()` and `by()` will be MUCH faster

```
from datatable import dt, f, by

df = dt.Frame(df)

df[:,
   dt.update(new_variable=dt.ifelse(-1*dt.shift(f.amount)==f.amount,2,1)),
   by(f.user,f.merchant,f.date)
]
```

Comment: This looks great! Let me try that. Also thank you so much for making me aware of this package in Python.

Comment: Out of curiosity are there any other packages from R that are in Python that you can recommend? I am new user to Python and a lot of my work evolves around data cleaning so I was wondering if there were other packages in Python that would make the transition easier?